# End to End encryption for messages with search functionality

Tags: flutter, encryption, getstream-chat

I am developing a flutter app with chat functionality and I am using [stream_chat_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/stream_chat_flutter) for chat functionality.
I need to implement [end to end encryption](https://www.techtarget.com/searchsecurity/definition/end-to-end-encryption-E2EE) on messages
I have followed documentation for encryption as given in the link below
https://getstream.io/chat/docs/sdk/flutter/guides/end_to_end_chat_encryption/

The issues with the encryption are:

1. The other user is not getting notification for encrypted message, while unencrypted text notification works. I am using firebase messaging integrated with getStream to send message.
2. The encrypted messages are normally decryped correctly, but sometimes when user sends the message, the received message is not as same as sent encrypted message thus it is not getting decrypted. It seems like the encrypted text are not getting saved correctly on getstream server.
3. How to implement the search messages functionality if all the messages are encrypted?

Comment: For 1, 2 we don't have any details for debugging. As for 3, searchable symmetric encryption has been defined, but it leaks information by definition, and I don't think that there are many libraries that support it (definitely not in the mainstream crypto libs, possibly because it is a higher level scheme).

Comment: Jumping on what Maarten has already said for 1 and 2 it is hard to give concrete advice without having details on the issues themselves. 
My first tip would be to try to identify at which stage of the process the error appears first to be able to narrow down the issue. 
Happy to help further when there's more information that we can analyze! 

As for point 3: nothing to add to the previous answer from Maarten.